# Buffer Overflow due to Query string length

Tags: asp.net-mvc, buffer-overflow

I am having a url like this,

http://domain.com?a=1&b=something&c=something

I am accessing all these query strings on the server side to do some process.

Now if someone sends in a large text of around 4036 characters for parameter b, I am getting a buffer overflow error.

What is the best way to handle this in ASP.NET MVC4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is due to reaching the maximum request length method. If so, you can solve this by setting the maximum request length to a higher value. You can change this value by setting the **maxRequestLength** attribute of the **httpRuntime** element:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <!-- This will set the maximum request length to 30720 KB (30MB).
             The default is 4096 KB (4MB) -->
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="30720" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```